# How to display the folder's columns for a document in a view in Sharepoint 2013 foundation?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to create a flat view that shows all documents in a list without folders, but I can't figure out how to get for each document the columns of the parent folder.

We have to keep the folders system, but be able to use filters on this view.

[View screenshot with folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peniO.png)

[View Screenshot without folders, where I need to get the folder columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N191n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a misunderstanding of the columns behavior, in fact you are displaying the same columns in both views (except for Modified, Index, ISO Language), however I assume what you really want is to display the same Field Values of the parent folder for each child item, that kind of behavior (values inheritance between folders and child items) isn't possible by just editing the view neither by applying some list settings.

First of all you need to understand that list items, documents and folders are all list items from the system perspective so they have individual properties for each one of them, a folder is just a special type of item that is able to contain other items (strictly speaking is just simulating a container).

In your case the Field Values that are being displayed in the columns of the folders view are values that belong to the folder itself but not to his child items. If you want to propagate those field values for the child items of each folder then you have two options:

- **Manually**: Assign the values to each child item by editing their
  properties using the Edit Form or using a Grid View to edit multiple
  items faster.
- **Automatically**: Create a Workflow or Event Receiver to copy the values
  of the parent folder to each new item/document that is added to the
  list/library.

However, as I can see your library is not being used in production yet, so my personal recommendation is to change your approach and use something **similar** to a Managed Metadata term store instead of folders (folders should be your last option to categorize items/documents, just for cases when you really don't have another way to achieve your goal), with the Managed Metadata approach you are able to apply tags to the items allowing them to belong to multiple categories and being filtered and searched more efficiently, but I know what you may be thinking "how can I do this if the Managed Metadata Service is not available in SharePoint Foundation", well thats why I said "use something similar", there should be more than one third party solution out there that will provide a similar functionality, but if you want to choose the less effort path, just use out-of-the-box Multi-choice field or Multi-lookup field, that you can start to using right now and assign the categories that you want to your items and create different views and filter them.

Comment: Ok, I better understand how folders are working.
As I will probably have to develop an external application (in C#) to manage selection and printing (with complicated alorithms), that view just will have to run in a short term.
I will probably use a workflow to simply do that for the moment, even if it's not really the best solution in my opinion to duplicate values.

Anyway thanks for your support !

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to create a new view, or modify an already existing one, in your library.

When you edit or create a new view you are presented with the "Edit view" screen, here you can  choose to "Show all files without folders" in the "Folders" section.

See e.g. for more details http://www.bloggedbychris.com/2013/10/19/flatten-document-library-list-sharepoint-2013-2010/ on this particular problem.

Comment: Yes I already did this, but the problem is that columns of the parent folder don't display in my view